# How can I only publish a subfolder to my Azure Website?

Tags: git, azure, bitbucket, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core

In Visual Studio 14 CTP I created a new "ASP.NET vNext Web Application".

I want to have a local git repository that I sync with my BitBucket repository.

I want to push my entire folder structure to Bitbucket which would include a folder I made for my SQL scripts but also the .sln file and everything else.

This is a portion of the folder structure Visual Studio made:

```
- MyApp  <-- I want this and below in BitBucket
-- MyApp.sln.ide
-- sqlscripts
-- src
---- MyApp  <-- I want only this and below to be deployed to Azure Website.
----- bin
----- Controllers
----- Models
----- wwwroot
```

I will push the entire folder structure to BitBucker, but I only want the second MyApp folder and below to go to Azure.

Can I tell Azure to just "take" that one MyApp folder and below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably a way to do this in visual Studio 14 CTP but as it's evolving pretty fast I lost track. Here is way to do it with command prompt.

`cd` into `src/MyApp` and run `kpm pack` there. This will create a publishable folder structure for you just for `src/MyApp` project (I assume you have project.json file under `src/MyApp` folder). You can now publish this folder to Azure Web Site through FTP for example. Instructions are here: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Deploy-an-AspNet-vNext-application-to-Microsoft-Azure-websites

Comment: Hi @tugberk, that looks like it will work for me but it makes me wonder if I'm doing something too far out of the norm.  Is there a better way with Azure to have a repository for deployment and keep your .sln files and such versioned and safe?  What do you do?

Comment: @user390480 when I use azure web sites, I generally publish my application using GIT publishing feature: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-publish-source-control/ I'm not sure how it will play with azure web sites though.